# Add new axis dynamically when adding series from indicators/stocktools

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Basically I have a case where I have some series already using more than one yAxis. I want to add a series indicator to one of those series. But it kind of breaks, because this new series goes out of the plot area.

yAxis definition:

```
    yAxis: [
      {}, 
      {
        opposite: false,
      }, 
    ],
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/t2ze3vLg/14/) is a working demo with that 'bug', if you try to add an indicator that generates a new axis ('Accumulation/Distribution' e.g.) the unexpected behavior happens.

I'd expect to add this new series/axis making then appear inside plot area and be able to remove that series and make this new axis be removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing this issue, it seems like a bug. I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread.

Link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13807